# How to make Array output use Side A text instead of Side B text

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have a question in regards to arrays and case switchers..

Basically, I'm working on a theme options page and currently have a select mechanism as such..

```
# Select Box
case 'select':
    $output .= '<select class="of-input" name="'. $value['id'] .'" id="'. $value['id'] .'">';

    $select_value = get_option($value['id']);

    asort($value['options']);
    reset($value['options']); 

    foreach ($value['options'] as $option) {
        $selected = '';

        if($select_value != '') {
            if ( $select_value == $option) { 
                $selected = ' selected="selected"';
            } 
        } 

        $output .= '<option'. $selected .'>';
        $output .= $option;
        $output .= '</option>';
    } 

    $output .= '</select>';
break;
```

Then, in theme options I make an array like this for my NivoSlider that I've added and the select option is working..

```
# NivoSlider Effect Options 
$hd_slider_effect_options = array( 
"random"=>  __('Random', 'hd'),
"sliceDownLeft" => __('Slice Down Left', 'hd'),
"sliceUp" => __('Slice Up', 'hd'),
"sliceUpLeft" => __('Slice Up Left', 'hd'),
"sliceUpDown" => __('Slice Up Down', 'hd'),
"sliceUpDownLeft" => __('Slice Up Down Left', 'hd'),
"fold" => __('Fold', 'hd'),
"fade" => __('Fade', 'hd'),
"slideInRight" => __('Slide In Right', 'hd'),
"slideInLeft" => __('Slide In Left', 'hd'),
"sliceDown" => __('Slice Down', 'hd')
);
```

But, now that I'm configuring theme options to work with slider, I ran into problems. When I look at my source code, it's adding a capital F for the fade option.. instead of side A output, it's outputting side B instead.. why?

Here's some code from my slider.php to make it a bit more clear..

```
<?php
$hd_slider_effect = get_option('theme_slider_effect');
$hd_slider_slices = get_option('theme_slider_slices'); 
$hd_slider_speed = get_option('theme_slider_speed'); 
$hd_slider_pause_time = get_option('theme_slider_pause_time'); 
$hd_slider_pause = get_option('theme_slider_pause'); 
$hd_slider_play = get_option('theme_slider_play');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hd-slider').nivoSlider({
        manualAdvance: <?php echo $hd_slider_play; ?>,
        effect: '<?php echo $hd_slider_effect; ?>',
        slices: <?php echo $hd_slider_slices; ?>,
        animSpeed: <?php echo $hd_slider_speed; ?>,
        //pauseTime: 5000,
        startSlide: 0,
        controlNav: true,
        keyboardNav: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        captionOpacity: 0.6,
        directionNav: true,
        directionNavHide: true
    });
});
});
</script>
```

And this is how it shows, in source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hd-slider').nivoSlider({
            manualAdvance: True, // this needs to be lowercase t
            effect: 'Fade', // this needs to be lowercase f
            slices: 10,
            animSpeed: 1000, 
            //pauseTime: 5000,
            startSlide: 0,
            controlNav: true,
            keyboardNav: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
        captionOpacity: 0.6,
        directionNav: true, 
            directionNavHide: true
        });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

So, anyone know how I can fix this problem? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: as @DevlshOne suggested use `effect: '<?php echo strtolower($hd_slider_effect); ?>',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtolower()` PHP function should solve that one for you.

Comment: Thanks a million guys, this fixed the problem. :) Sorry for the terrible English, it's my fourth language so I have difficulties expressing my questions sometimes.

Comment: Great! Please upvote and accept this answer if that works for you.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but it said I need 15 reputation.. hence I thanked you in person and accepted the answer ;)